# Alfa Wireless Card disconnects randomly from VirtualBox Linux Guest

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I have an Alfa wireless card connected to VirtualBox running a Linux guest. It works, and I can connect to networks, but then it disconnects shortly afterwards. I have to bring the wlan0 interface down, then back up again for it to work, yet it breaks again and so on.

I tried running the card on the host OS and it worked flawlessly.

I tried changing one of my VirtualBox emulated networks from wlan0 to eth0, thinking it might have caused some sort on conflict internally in VirtualBox code or something (did that from VirtualBox network settings of the VM).

I tried simple reboot and simple re-plug of the card.

I tried reinstalling VirtualBox.

Lastly, from my research, it seems that VirtualBox doesn't support USB 3.0. I **only** have USB 3.0 ports on my physical hardware. Could that be the problem? (PS. the Alfa wireless card is USB 2.0 device).

How can I eliminate such disconnections from the wireless network?

`dmesg` output:

```
[    2.504426] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    2.665305] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8187
[    2.665313] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.665318] usb 2-1: Product: RTL8187_Wireless
[    2.665323] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Manufacturer_Realtek_RTL8187_
[    2.665327] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 00C0CA75A88A
[    8.032857] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8187
[ 4081.888912] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 4468.756667] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 4468.915878] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8187
[ 4468.915889] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4468.915896] usb 2-1: Product: RTL8187_Wireless
[ 4468.915901] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Manufacturer_Realtek_RTL8187_
[ 4468.915907] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 00C0CA75A88A
[ 4924.843184] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 7616.296434] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 7616.453921] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8187
[ 7616.453929] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7616.453934] usb 2-1: Product: RTL8187_Wireless
[ 7616.453939] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Manufacturer_Realtek_RTL8187_
[ 7616.453944] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 00C0CA75A88A
```

Comment: You should check the drivers on host and guest. Are they any different? Remember to check the version number and firmware

Comment: Would you help me through that? How do I do it?

Comment: UPDATE: Yes, they're the same.

Comment: Actually, I have this problem since kernel 3.16. without virtualisation.
Maybe try 3.17...

Comment: A problem with your USB shows up in *dmesg*. Try *dmesg* | *grep -i usb*.

Comment: I've added the output in the OP, @MariusMatutiae.

Comment: @davidbaumann, I have `3.11-2-amd64` kernel in Host (works), yet I have `3.14-kali1-amd64` on Guest (doesn't).